# How to calculate normalised ratio indices in all possible band combinations and then correlation with environmental variables in R?

Tags: r, combinations

I want to calculate normalised ratio and simple ratio indices in all possible band combinations and then want to correlate with environmental variables in R. Then I want to identify the best combination giving the highest correlation. The implementation is available in `hsdar` package in R. But it is very slow for a large dataset. I am attaching a small dataset here

```
Environmental_variable  WV_400  WV_401  WV_402  WV_403  WV_404  WV_405
95.512  0.035   0.034   0.034   0.034   0.034   0.034
97.900  0.047   0.047   0.047   0.046   0.046   0.046
92.897  0.004   0.004   0.006   0.008   0.009   0.009
94.209  0.011   0.012   0.013   0.016   0.017   0.017
87.472  0.010   0.010   0.011   0.014   0.015   0.015
91.109  0.010   0.011   0.013   0.015   0.016   0.016
92.830  0.024   0.025   0.026   0.028   0.029   0.029
```

I am giving one example code from `hsdar` package for reference

```
library(hsdar)
data(spectral_data)
## Calculate normalised ratio indices in all possible combinations
nri_WV <- nri(spectral_data, recursive = TRUE)
## Build glm-models
glmnri <- glm.nri(nri_WV ~ chlorophyll, preddata = spectral_data)
## Return best 10 models
BM <- nri_best_performance(glmnri, n = 10, coefficient = "p.value")
```

Any help in the form of R code as a fast alternative to the `hsdar` package is highly appreciated.

Comment: Probably it's worth to look into [parallel computing](https://nceas.github.io/oss-lessons/parallel-computing-in-r/parallel-computing-in-r.html), I don't know how to cluster the `glm.nri` function, though.